# SQL Server Agent in Azure SQL cloud Database

Tags: azure, sql-server-agent

I have create a job in my SQL Sever Agent in my on prem database.  Now I want to move my database to Azure Cloud database but how I can schedule my job at Azure cloud database?  Can I use my management Studio connect to the cloud database and create a job over the management studio?

Answer (score 1):

This page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/job-automation-overview?view=azuresql

says "SQL Agent Jobs are not available in Azure SQL Database".  They are available in Azure SQL Managed instance.

For Azure SQL Database there are several options depending on what your jobs do and whether you have experience with any of the options.

- Link above for Elastic Jobs
- Logic Apps
- Data Factory
- Azure Functions